# Is there a way to display JSON data through a slider or carousel in jQuery or JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel

I have some JSON data as below:

```
[
   {
      "facility_name":"Center A",
      "process_delay":0,
      "lost_misplaced":7
   },
   {
      "facility_name":"Center B",
      "process_delay":0,
      "lost_misplaced":6
   },
   {
      "facility_name":"Center C",
      "process_delay":0,
      "lost_misplaced":15
   }
]
```

I'd like to be able to display this data using sliders or carousel. Such that the sliders from this JSON data will be like in the format:

```
Center A (process_delay)
Center A (lost_misplaced)
```

Such that from the JSON data, this becomes:

```
Center A 0    NEXT SLIDER    Center B 0    NEXT SLIDE      Center C 0
Center A 7                   Center B 6                    Center C 15
```

Comment: I would suggest to add the code you tried so far

Comment: So you have three questions: a) is there a way to display text using a carousel; b) how should I design a slide displaying text; and c) how do I extract each slide contents from my JSON data. a) and c) have been asked many times before, you'll be able to find answers using a search engine. b) is off-topic here. If you run into a specific problem with any of them and you can't find a solution for it, that's what you should ask about. Please read [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick one.
Uses [BootstrapVue](https://bootstrap-vue.org/), which is JavaScript (& CSS).
No jQuery.

```js
Vue.component('paragraph', {
  props: ['item', 'prop'],
  template: `<p><span v-text="item.facility_name"></span> (<span v-text="item[prop]"></span>)</p>`
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    slide: 0,
    items: [{
      facility_name:"Center A",
      process_delay:0,
      lost_misplaced:7
   }, {
      facility_name:"Center B",
      process_delay:0,
      lost_misplaced:6
   }, {
      facility_name:"Center C",
      process_delay:0,
      lost_misplaced:15
   }]
  })
})
```

```css
.carousel-item {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}
.carousel-caption:not(#_) {
  bottom: 50%;
  transform: translateY(50%);
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}
.carousel-caption p:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.css" />
<script src="//polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=es2015%2CIntersectionObserver"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.12"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <b-carousel v-model="slide" controls background="#ababab">
    <b-carousel-slide v-for="item in items"
                      :key="item.facility_name"
                      img-blank>
        <paragraph :item="item" prop="process_delay"></paragraph>
        <paragraph :item="item" prop="lost_misplaced"></paragraph>
    </b-carousel-slide>
  </b-carousel>
</div>
```

Comment: Good one! I however wanted the implementation in JQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Use this simple slider
https://supersimpleslider.com/

Add the element for the slider

```
<div class="slider"></div>
```

Use jQuery to add your elements

```
    var myObj = [
   {
      "facility_name":"Center A",
      "process_delay":0,
      "lost_misplaced":7
   },
   {
      "facility_name":"Center B",
      "process_delay":0,
      "lost_misplaced":6
   },
   {
      "facility_name":"Center C",
      "process_delay":0,
      "lost_misplaced":15
   }
]

$.each(myObj, function(i,v){
  $('.slider').append(
    '<div class="just_text">' + v.facility_name + " " + v.process_delay + "<br />" + v.facility_name + " " + v.lost_misplaced +  '</div>'
  );
})
```

Consider adding some error control and conditions when the values are empty or wrong data